# How to rebind terminal shortcut in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I use the stadndard terminal that is shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to rebind the shortcut `Alt + f` and `Alt + b` to `Alt + ->` and `Alt + <-` correspondingly.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with "standard terminal" the `gnome-terminal`, you can change the hotkeys in the menu

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts
```

Other terminals have similar possibilites in menues at almost equal preferences locations. E.g, in the `terminator` terminal it is:

```
RightClick -> Preferences -> Key Bindings
```

[image: Changing key bindings in the terminator terminal]

Btw: Please consider looking for non-programming Ubuntu related questions in the [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) community, where this would be a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704648/how-to-change-command-line-keyboard-shortcuts).